# Find intersection point of two ListLinePlot's in mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a lot of experimental data that I plot as 2 curves using ListLinePlot in mathematica. I want to find the intersection point between those two. Can I do that without making an interpolation function and Solve[]? I really don't think it's necessary to make a polynomial with order of 1000 or whatever it will be in my case. It should be simple, but I can't find a function that does that. I'm perfectly fine with a function that assumes straight lines between each data point as ListLinePlot does (since there are so many of them). I feel like this should be very obvious, but I really can't find out how to do it (except for just using my eyes offcourse)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would actually use Mathematica's [`Interpolation`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Interpolation.html) function to generate the interpolants of the two curves, and then use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FindRoot.html) to find the intersection, as follows

```
curve1 = Interpolation[ data1 ];
curve2 = Interpolation[ data2 ];

FindRoot[ curve1[x] - curve2[x], {x, bestguess} ]
```

Despite the thousands of points involved, interpolation is a very fast operation, and on my machine there isn't a noticeable delay between pressing <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd> and Mathematica returning.

There is a caveat to this, though. As this is experimental data, the intersection itself will have an uncertainty, and I suggest you use a fitting method designed to generate that information, such as found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/15512/6109). While not immediately accessible, it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: You can use `InterpolationOrder -> 1` to force linear interpolation ("straight lines").  It might make it necessary to use a `FindRoot` method that does not depend on derivatives though.